TypeError: empty_like(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not NoneType
I'm trying to fine-tune the "unsloth/Llama-3.2-11B-Vision-Instruct" model using the DPOTrainer from trl. My dataset is trl-lib/rlaif-v, and I verified its format aligns with the requirements for DPO training. However, when I run the code on Kaggle, I encounter the following error during training:
Copy code
TypeError: empty_like(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not NoneType

Code
Here is the relevant code snippet:
model, tokenizer = FastVisionModel.from_pretrained(
    "unsloth/Llama-3.2-11B-Vision-Instruct",
    load_in_4bit = True, # Use 4bit to reduce memory use. False for 16bit LoRA.
    use_gradient_checkpointing = "unsloth", # True or "unsloth" for long context
)
model = FastVisionModel.get_peft_model(
    model,
    finetune_vision_layers     = True, # False if not finetuning vision layers
    finetune_language_layers   = True, # False if not finetuning language layers
    finetune_attention_modules = True, # False if not finetuning attention layers
    finetune_mlp_modules       = True, # False if not finetuning MLP layers
    r = 16,           # The larger, the higher the accuracy, but might overfit
    lora_alpha = 16,  # Recommended alpha == r at least
    lora_dropout = 0,
    bias = "none",
    random_state = 3407,
    use_rslora = False,  # We support rank stabilized LoRA
    loftq_config = None, # And LoftQ
)
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("trl-lib/rlaif-v", split="train[:1%]")
from trl import DPOConfig, DPOTrainer
training_args = DPOConfig(
        output_dir="output",
        fp16=True,
        gradient_checkpointing=True,
        per_device_train_batch_size=2,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=32,
        num_train_epochs=1,
        dataset_num_proc=4, # tokenization will use 32 processes
        dataloader_num_workers=4, # data loading will use 32 workers
        logging_steps=1,
    )
trainer = DPOTrainer(
        model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=dataset,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
    )

trainer.train()

Error Details
The error occurs at this point in the traceback:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 20
      2 training_args = DPOConfig(
      3         output_dir="output",
      4         fp16=True,
   (...)
     11         logging_steps=1,
     12     )
     13 trainer = DPOTrainer(
     14         model,
     15         args=training_args,
     16         train_dataset=dataset,
     17         tokenizer=tokenizer,
     18     )
---> 20 trainer.train()
...
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/unsloth_zoo/loss_utils.py:74, in patch_loss_functions.<locals>.UnslothForCausalLMLoss(logits, labels, vocab_size, num_items_in_batch, ignore_index, **kwargs)
     70 def UnslothForCausalLMLoss(
     71     logits, labels, vocab_size: int, num_items_in_batch: int = None, ignore_index: int = -100, **kwargs
     72 ):
     73     shift_logits = logits
---> 74     shift_labels = torch.empty_like(labels)
     75     shift_labels[..., :-1] = labels[..., 1:]
     76     shift_labels[..., -1] = ignore_index

TypeError: empty_like(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not NoneType

But I think the format of the dpo dataset is correct.
How to solve it?
What I've Tried
Verified the dataset format is correct for DPO training.
Tried using other datasets, but the error persists.
Checked that the dataset has valid input fields (logits, labels, etc.).
